# EF6 Modified state throws exception

Tags: entity-framework-6

I've read through most of the comments and feedback on exactly the same question on Stackoverflow and elsewhere and none of the solutions worked for me.

My scenario.

I have an Edit screen that populates data from a ViewModal.

Once the user clicks on the Update button, I use AutoMapper to map the ViewModel back to the entity, so I can update the data.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(Core.ViewModels.BuildingViewModel model)
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Building | Edit";

    try
    {
        var entity = model.ToEntity<BuildingViewModel, Core.Entities.Building>();
        Transactions.Broker.AskFor.Building.Update(entity);

        return Json(new { IsSuccess = true, Message = "Building successfully updated", Identity = entity.Id });
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

What bugs me is the fact that, at this point, I have no entity framework entity reference, a simple POCO gets mapped from a ViewModel.

Why would EF tell me that it cannot Attach / Add or Modify the entity because of an existing primary key? Is that not what an update is, taking an entity that already exist, and saving the changes down?

In the UoW, the edit looks like this (commented out what I have tried already):

```
public virtual SpaceResult<T> Edit(T entity)
{
    SpaceResult<T> result = new SpaceResult<T>();

    try
    {
        this._context.Entry<T>(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        result.IsError = true;
        result.Message = ex.Message;
        result.InnerException = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : string.Empty;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I also don't see the purpose of turning off Tracking for the Context, which seems to fix the problem.

Am I missing something within the EF, or trying to do something that is not support?

Comment: Do you have the exact text of the exception?

Comment: That error usually means that an entity with that primary key had previously been loaded into the context, so it won't let you attach another (new) entity with the same key.